# Debugging Jest Tests in VS Code: Breakpoints Move

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

When debugging *Jest* tests in *VS-Code* my breakpoints move a few lines as soon as I start the debugger.

I use the officially [recommended configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-jest-tests) with plain JavaScript (not Babel).

I think it has something to do with source maps.
Setting `"sourceMaps": false` in the configuration makes my breakpoints not move anymore but shift the 'real' source code a few lines.

**Minimal Example:**

```js
// hello_world.test.js

funTest = require('./hello_world.js')

const x = 15

test('this is a test', () => {
    expect(funTest(5)).toBe(9)
})
```

```js
// hello_world.js
const funTest = () => {
    return 9 
}

module.exports= funTest
```

Now if you set a breakpoint at `const x = 15` you will see that it is shifted to `expect(funTest(5)).toBe(9)` during the debugging session.

**Used Software**
VS Code: 1.27.0, no extensions ; Jest: 23.5.0 ; Node: 8.10.0 ; Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Comment: Can you add a minimal code example?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll paste it.

Answer (score 29):

I found out the 'solution' myself.
Add a .babelrc file into your root folder with the following content:

```
{
  "sourceMap": "inline",
  "retainLines": true
}
```

Then the problems are gone.

Even though I do not use Babel specifically, VS Code somewhat does.

Comment: I've been searching for two days... thank you!!

Comment: Has no effect with ts-jest.

Answer (score 11):

Add the following to your `vscode-jest-tests` config in `launch.json`:

```
{
  "disableOptimisticBPs": true
}
```

This worked for me and [several other people](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5319).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this over nine-thousand times.

Comment: maybe vscode should rename the option "disablePullingHairOut" and make `true` be the default value.

Comment: This worked for a while and then stopped working with recent vscode updates.  Infuriating.

Comment: Can confirm, this option no longer works as of 2020 updates

Answer (score 4):

This is a long standing question and searching for a solution leads to old or wrong answers, like that suggestion to add "disableOptimisticBPs: true", which is no longer supported. I couldn't even find a note saying that it was removed and why.

The main problem here is clearly the source map. For some reasons the generated source maps don't match the actual TS code. And for me not even breakpoints in the normal code worked (outside of test code). But in another project I have a working Mocha configuration, which finally brought me to a solution here.

You don't need `ts-jest` for debugging! It's the culprit for the entire trouble, which caused not only for me to lose days, searching for a solution. Instead let `tsc` generate your JS code (as you probably do anyway) and make it generating source maps too. Then just give Jest the path to the JS files, not the TS files. VS Code will automatically find the sidecar source maps and step with you through your TS code just fine.

As launch configuration to debug the current spec file use:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Run current Jest test",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--inspect-brk",
                "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
                "--runInBand",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.js",
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/output/src/**/*.js"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "testing"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This needs a task to run the TS compiler:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "command": "tsc",
            "label": "tsc",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "-w",
                "-p",
                "."
            ],
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "silent",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

which builds all file on first test debug run and then watches for any changes in the TS files and recompiles those changed immediately.

Now select any of your spec files, set a breakpoint (and maybe also in your source code) and start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VSCode, what I have found extremely easy is to open Javascript Debug Terminal(instead of Run and Debug) and then run your jest test and it will work like a charm. [image]